# Dynamic read from file using java String.split

Tags: java, string, dynamic, split

I've got a file that contains something like this:

```
Hello;my name;is Marco
I want;some cheese
Hi
this;is;a;test
```

As you can see I have some words which are separated by a `;`. Number of elements in the rows are not fixed, so I need a dynamic way of reading each row. I tried using `String split` method, this way for each row that I'm reading:

```
String supp = "";
while((supp = read.split(";")[i]) != null){
     i++;
}
System.out.println("Number of elements: " + i);
```

But of course it's not working (`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`).

**How can I read the whole file dynamically?**

Comment: 1. read each line 2. split each line into a splitArray 3. loop from 0 to splitArray.length 4. go back to 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`split` gives you an array so you should use it:

```
String[] parts = read.split(";");
System.out.println("Number of elements: " + parts.length);
```

You shouldn't check size of array using indexing. Each array has `length` field that gives you it's size.

If you need to read file you can use `BufferedReader` that has handy method for reading file line by line. Check this question: [How to read a large text file line by line using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868369/how-to-read-a-large-text-file-line-by-line-in-java)

Comment: Oh my god man, I missed it so bad! Thank you for your answer! I feel such a noob...